# Хедер в одну линию

Tags: html, css

В хедере должна быть картинка, текст и меню с ссылками, меню и текст встали в одну линию, а вот картинка находится выше их, хотя они все находятся в одном блоке `div` и должно работать `display:inline-block;`

Что я делаю не так?

```css
.slider {
  background-image: url('images/slider-bg.jpg');
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1024px;
}
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
.header div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#logo h1 {
  color: black;
}
#navigation {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
#navigation a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div id="logo">

    <img src="images/logo.png">

    <h1>Waxom</h1>
  </div>
  <!--end logo-->
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="*">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Shortcodes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Contact</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <!--end navigation-->
  </div>
  <!--end navigation-->

</div>
<!--end header-->
```

Comment: h1 - относиться к блочным элементам

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/cpxwa919/

Comment: Может нужно дописать в стили
`#logo img {float: left;}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `display` не наследуется, поэтому для дочерних элементов его надо задавать.
В вашем случае его на задать для `#logo h1`

```css
.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
.header div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#logo h1 {
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
#navigation {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
#navigation a:link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <div id="logo">

    <img src="images/logo.png">

    <h1>Waxom</h1>
  </div>
  <!--end logo-->
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>

      <li>
        <a href="*">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Shortcodes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="*">Contact</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <!--end navigation-->
  </div>
  <!--end navigation-->

</div>
<!--end header-->
```